# How to select each row into a variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a function that turns a delimited list into a table:

```
select * from dbo.fn_rpt_ParseValues('abc|123|test','|')
```

Results:

```
abc
123
test
```

How can I get each row into a SQL variable?  For example:

```
@Name = 'abc'
@Phone = '123'
@Comment = 'test'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Very inefficiently...You should rethink your method.  It will be more efficient to just put them into variables from the delimited string I suspect

Comment: Why are you trying to get them into variables anyway? You're not thinking of doing something with them in a loop are you? If so, parsing the list to a table and performing set based operations would be magnitudes faster.

Comment: The stored procedure returns rows back to a .NET data grid.  There are other columns that are normal, but one is pipe delimited but I have to return them as individual columns.

Comment: @user390480 You want them as **columns** or as **rows**?

Comment: Can you change `fn_rpt_ParseValues`? If so, just change it to return each value in a separate column, then you can assign them to variables in a single `SELECT`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
declare @S varchar(100) = 'abc|123|test'

declare @Name varchar(10)
declare @Phone varchar(10)
declare @Comment varchar(10)

select @Name = X.value('x[1]', 'varchar(10)'),
       @Phone = X.value('x[2]', 'varchar(10)'),
       @Comment = X.value('x[3]', 'varchar(10)')
from (select cast('<x>'+replace(@S, '|', '</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml)) as T(X)

select @Name, @Phone, @Comment
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Split table(
     RowIndex int IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,Item varchar(200));
INSERT INTO @Split 
    SELECT * from dbo.fn_rpt_ParseValues('abc|123|test','|');

DECLARE @Name   varchar(50);
DECLARE @Phone  varchar(50);
DECLARE @Comment varchar(100);
SET @Name   =  (SELECT Item FROM @Split WHERE RowIndex=1);
SET @Phone  =  (SELECT Item FROM @Split WHERE RowIndex=2);
SET @Comment = (SELECT Item FROM @Split WHERE RowIndex=3);
```

Comment: Alternatively, pivot the results and then you can do `SELECT @name = Field1, @Phone = Field2, etc`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the rows are ordered, you want to do a pivot to turn them into columns.

Another option is to have your parse function (or a modified version) return a single row result set (table-valued function) and use CROSS/OUTER APPLY to append them to a row:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174853.aspx